# How to fix blank page after POST

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, webpack

I have a Rails 6 app with VueJS 2.0 and Webpacker. Everything works, until I submit a form via POST using Rails. I get a blank page, but if I refresh, everything is fine again.

I've tried using `$mount("#app")` to no avail

My application.js looks like:

```
 require("@rails/ujs").start()
 import Vue from "vue/dist/vue.esm";
 import ExampleComponent from "../components/example_component.vue";

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   components: {
     ExampleComponent
   },
  })
 });
```

My application.html.erb looks like:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
<div id='app'>
  <%= yield %>
</div><!--/#app-->
```

My Rails controller is returning the following:

```
Started PATCH "/books/fsaddsdsf-1cb1c13b8fc6"
Processing by BooksController#update as HTML
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/books

Started GET "/books/fsaddsdsf-1cb1c13b8fc6"...
Processing by BooksController#show as HTML
```

My rails forms are just standard `<%= form_with %>` forms with `local: true` turned on. They work perfectly without the javascript.

There are not any Rails or VueJS error messages in the console which is weird.

Comment: Check your Rails server log: It'll indicate what's happening.

Comment: We do need yours a Rails route handler code. Do you return just a json response from it? Or some kind of view (i am not familiar with rails terminology)?

Comment: @JoshBrody, the Rails server log just returns a normal POST, that then redirects to a show.html.erb view. It's just generated from a default rails scaffold command.

Comment: @GONG, It's not a JSON response, the form POSTs, then gets redirected to a HTML Page. It's definitely the javascripts fault that the page is blank, if I block Javascript, the form submittion works fine.

Comment: Can u show us the POST action and returned js response? basically after submitting the form, it will load your returned js format. I'm not Vue master, I just think there's an issue in your returned js  file after the POST action

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). But to prevent default form submission with full page refresh you would need to add .prevent modifier in submitting button

`<button @click.prevent="methodCall">Submit</button>`

Comment: It is better to just add ```@submit.prevent``` to the form.

Comment: It’s does pretty much same thing.

Comment: It doesn't. Click prevent acts like a button click. Submit prevent acts like a form submit. For example default HTML5 form validation (required inputs) will be handled well. Also, if you have complex form it is much easier for everyone in your team to find submit handler.

Comment: OP didn’t ask about client side form validation. Even it is the case then I wouldn’t hold my breath on HTML5 form validation instead i’d go for vee-validate. You can use type=“submit” in any button in the form to make it submit button. However it defeats the purpose of using vue isnt it.

Comment: Then, why do you even need a form for click prevent? It is all about usability and accessibility (screen reader will tell you, when your form being submitted. But will ignore non-native way to handle submission.). You need to use default browser behaviour as much as possible. It is clear to me that OP is newbie in ```Vue```. And you already teaching him a bad practice.

Comment: @ShirishNigam, I don't want to submit the form via AJAX. I'm looking to submit the form via normal Rails (which works, until I add the javascript).

Comment: There are multiple ways to do the same thing in Programming world and that's what i love about it. This is one of them. You can be usability, accessibility and good practice police for all i care. People generally focus on solving the core problem rather than putting all bells and whistles even before they get something working. It's now up to OP to decide how he wants to proceed and learn further. Over and out !!

Comment: @coldicetea, If you want to use the Rails way to submit the form then you can simply put submit button in form and make sure you have method and action setup correctly. Keep in mind, that will trigger full page refresh unless you want to avoid that. Now to tackle, the "blank page" situation, when you are submitting the form to the action method, then make sure you are returning a response from the method.

Comment: @ShirishNigam, Unfortunately, there must be something I'm missing with Vue, as the Rails form submission is working (there is a server responding with an HTML page), until I add the Vue Code which causes the blank screen on the redirect.

Comment: could you show your ExampleComponent and rails controller

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and ended up here looking for a solution. Not sure if this will fix this particular case (I am not using vuejs), but I discovered that if I was getting a blank page after a POST and successful GET redirect, the problem was due to the `X-XSS-Protection` header, which defaults to `1` in Rails. That header tells the browser to not load anything on a page that tries to run the same scripts that were submitted in the POST. So perhaps some of your javascript is being posted in the request?

In my case I have a CMS that allows iframe embeds, but when someone updated a page with an iframe in it, it appeared successful on the server but failed to load in the browser. The workaround I found was:

```rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :disable_xss_protection

  ...

  private

  def disable_xss_protection
    # allows a page to display after an iframe or javascript was submitted in the post
    response.headers['X-XSS-Protection'] = "0"
  end

end
```

**Warning:** Disabling cross-site-scripting protection is dangerous, so I would only use this approach in a situation where you have 100% protection against malicious users reaching the controller.